# Migrate PHP pages of a website into Word Press

Tags: php, wordpress

My website is half Word Press based and other half in `PHP` pages. What I want to do is migrate `PHP` individual pages into Word Press too. How do I do that?

Comment: its too abstract, there are several ways.. but manually. you can perhaps script it out. but idk we can find the tools for this.

Comment: Script? What do you mean

Comment: crawl the entire site and create an article for each page if possible. but that definitely limited to text items, not for forms and its equivalent.

Comment: I need the forms e.t.c

Comment: thats not possible unless you remake everything then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know PHP or can hire someone who knows PHP then you can follow this plan:

WordPress is made in PHP so you can take existing php pages, and try to build custom page templates based on those codes and then assign to each page that custom template from WordPress and insert content.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

For forms related fields, you can use plugin for forms, then use short-code to insert those forms inside your pages.

Two free options are: Contact Form 7 [1] (it is more than a contact form, you can add lot of custom fields). And another is Ninja Forms [2], it has every type of field you ever need.

[1] https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/
[2] https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms/

Also if you need something i.e. key values data related to each custom page, you can use Custom Fields within WordPress and save data, then in the template access those fields and use in Php i.e. `get_post_meta($post_id,'field_key');` it will output array of data of values to that fields and you can use in your php template.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

If you need professional looking interface for Custom fields, then you can use a plugin called ACF[3] or library called CMB2[4] with its lovely documentation[5]

[3] https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/
[4] https://wordpress.org/plugins/cmb2/
[5] https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Basic-Usage